# Is it possible to create subproject in existing android project?

Tags: android

I am following this tutorial: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Contacts/ I have created the Dialtacts project already and now the tutorial says i need to create another project with name tests in Dialtacts.

When i tried to create subproject in eclipse it gave me following error:
D:\workspace\Dialtacts overlaps the location of another project: 'Dialtacts'

Now what should i do to run this tutorial?

Comment: Does it mean just create another project rather than a sub project?

Comment: Having had a look I see what you mean. Have you tried making a directory 'test' and point eclipse to that ad the root dir?

Comment: The link you supplied is not a tutorial. It is a terribly out of date copy of an application from the Android firmware. It is not designed to be built via Eclipse as a standalone application.

Comment: @kerubu the main activity file of test has different namesapce. so it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Other than just try and build it in a new directory I don't know.